# How to store service provider specific data without it influencing your database table design

Tags: rest, data-structures, microservices, integration, software-design

Let's say you're providing a certain service or feature on your app that requires you to integrate with an external service provider, say for example, a package delivery provider. When you request a delivery to be done through their api, this external api returns a bunch of extra values that you might or might not need now or in the future. The problems I see are:

1. To store this data in your PackageDeliveries sql table, you might end up needing to add columns in this table to fit those extra values, the problem here is that now your database table is taking the shape of your service provider's data and doesn't necessarily revolve anymore around your business model.
2. If you switch to another service provider for any reason, your database now has to take the shape of this and the previous provider's data.

What is the best practice when it comes to storing external provider's data without it influencing your generic business data model?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice when it comes to storing external provider's data without it influencing your generic business data model is to use a denormalized data model.

Here is an example of a denormalized data model for storing package delivery data:

```
PackageDeliveries
  id
  tracking_number
  status
  provider_data
    delivery_date
    delivery_time
    delivery_location
```

The provider_data column stores the data from the external provider's API. This data is stored in its original format, so it can be easily understood by the external provider.

The PackageDeliveries table only stores the essential data for your business model, such as the tracking number, status, and provider. This data is stored in a normalized format, so it is easy to query and manipulate.

By using a denormalized data model, you can store the data from external providers without it influencing your generic business data model. This makes your data model more flexible and easier to maintain.